Django Model OneToOneField migrations cannot encounter column
Hello im learning Django and trying to add a new table where I save my isbn numbers and I wanted to make onetoone relation book with isbn number. Django creates the tables of isbn and books aswell. the problem when I do the onetoonefield.
models.py
from django.db import models

class BookNumber(models.Model):
    isbn_10 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    isbn_13 = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=False, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=266, blank=True, unique=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    published = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='covers/', blank=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='covers/', blank=True)
    numbers = models.OneToOneField(BookNumber, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

when I uncomment the numbers it throws the next error:
virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 329, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: **no such column: demo_book.number_id**

from the SQLLite:
sqlite> .tables
auth_group                  demo_book                 
auth_group_permissions      demo_booknumber           
auth_permission             django_admin_log          
auth_user                   django_content_type       
auth_user_groups            django_migrations         
auth_user_user_permissions  django_session            
authtoken_token           
sqlite> .schema demo_book
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "demo_book" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "title" varchar(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "cover" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "description" text NOT NULL, "file" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "is_published" bool NOT NULL, "price" decimal NOT NULL, "published" date NULL);
sqlite> .schema demo_booknumber
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "demo_booknumber" ("isbn_10" varchar(10) NOT NULL, "isbn_13" varchar(13) NOT NULL, "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);

Can you please help?
I have erased the sqlite db and recreated the DB and I have added id fields or not it didn't fix the error. Obviously I also asked chatgpt and follow the steps suggested aswell. It's this one line that gives the problem. models.OneToOneField. I did make migrations and migrations aswell.
Makemigrations error:
(virtenv) merolat@MacBook-Air-de-Mert MovieListApp % python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 329, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: demo_book.numbers_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 454, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 42, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 61, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, "url_patterns", [])
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 738, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 731, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/first/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('demo/', include('demo.urls')),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 39, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/demo/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/demo/views.py", line 12, in <module>
    class Another(View):
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/demo/views.py", line 17, in Another
    for book in books:
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 400, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1928, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 91, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1562, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 122, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/merolat/Documents/Projects/PythonReactPostgre/MovieListApp/virtenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 329, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: demo_book.numbers_id


Did you uncomment the field when running makemigrations and migrate? Also on the model design do you really need a separate model for the ISBN data if its a one to one with your model and there's no other dependencies between the data? Wouldn't either of those ISBN number fields be a candidate key for your book table?

Hello yes when I uncomment the field it fails. if I comment it runs but doent create the relation obviously. I mean I do it because as I said im learning. im just trying to understand why it fails and how it supposed to work.

makemigrations fails when you uncomment the field? Can you share the complete error traceback?

just added the full error

In MovieListApp/demo/views.py there's a class Another which is looping over a queryset (for book in books). You should not be evaluating a queryset (looping, using the len method on it, etc.) anywhere it can get run when Django is loading up.

number_id is suspicious as I can't see it anywhere else in your posted code.

@Marco I believe their numbers field is actually named number, foreign keys / one to one fields like that are automatically suffixed with an _id by Django to create the column name for the database.

Yes sure, but error message is numbers, code is number. The poster may mixing some things up.

I think @AbduAzizBarkat resolved the issue. Removing the view Another let me do the makemigratins and migrate.
why this happens and how views it is related to the DB creation process? This is so strange Django and ChatGPT is not able to figure out this issue :D
#class Another(View):
#books = Book.objects.all()
books = Book.objects.filter(is_published=True)

output = ''
for book in books:
output += f"we have {book.title} book with id {book.id} is the right id. "

def get(self, request):
return HttpResponse(self.output)

@atlaspp that's a well known thing. You should not run database queries on the module level before Django has completely loaded up. The class definition runs when that Python file gets imported and Django needs to resolve all of the imports to be able to go ahead with the migrations. In fact even without this issue running that query there is a bug since you'll then be showing the user stale (old) data since the data won't get updated when new entries are added or updated, etc.

I've closed this with a duplicate target although there's probably better targets out there. If you find a more suitable target feel free to ping me and I'll update the closure to point to it instead.
